# How to increase the border thickness of a column in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

[image]

in the image shown below the border thickness between withdrawal date and issue date is more compared to the thickness between currency and amount. can anyone help me to change the thickness is there any property to change this (oracle forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not its *thickness*; you should just **separate** `currency` and `amount`, i.e. move `amount` a little bit *right* and - visually - you'll see the difference.